# SQL comparing a few values in select

Tags: sql, compare

so i have 2 tables in SQL, Patients and Patients_Treatments which are connected with patient.id as main key
what i wanna do is take a specific patient and see what treatments he has done so i have this code:

```
SELECT (Treatment_code)
FROM Patients_Treatments
Where Patient_ID = '999999999'
```

now what i want do is take all the patients from Patient tabel that have had the same treatments code (or more treatments) just as patient '99999999'

so if patient '9999999' had treatments 111,222,333 
and i have a patient that had treatment 111,222,555 - it wont show him
but if had had treatments 111,222,333 or 111,222,333,444 - it will show him

im having problem with how to do a loop so i make sure it check that all the treatments that patient 99999999 has done, also the person im checking has done as well

thanks!

Comment: Can you tag the RDMS you are using please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume this is the metadata and the examples you provided.

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENTS
(PATIENT_ID INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE PATIENTS_TREATMENTS
(PATIENT_ID INTEGER, TREATMENT_CODE INTEGER);

INSERT INTO PATIENTS VALUE (999999999),(1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO PATIENTS_TREATMENTS VALUE 
(999999999, 111),(999999999, 222),(999999999, 333),
(1, 111),(1, 222),(1, 555),
(2, 111),(2, 222),(2, 333),
(3, 111),(3, 222),(3, 333),(3,444);
```

The solution would be as follows

```
SELECT 
      PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID 

   FROM PATIENTS

   INNER JOIN PATIENTS_TREATMENTS MYTREATMENT    
   ON PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID              = MYTREATMENT.PATIENT_ID

   LEFT JOIN PATIENTS_TREATMENTS COMPARETREATMENT 
   ON  COMPARETREATMENT.TREATMENT_CODE = MYTREATMENT.TREATMENT_CODE
   AND COMPARETREATMENT.PATIENT_ID     = '999999999'

   WHERE PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID <> '999999999'

   GROUP BY PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID
   HAVING COUNT(COMPARETREATMENT.TREATMENT_CODE) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PATIENTS_TREATMENTS WHERE PATIENT_ID = '999999999')
```

Try it on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: this works well for me, but i don't understand everything can you please explain?
the last row does only the count, but for some reason the code does work and if the treatment id is not the same it wont show, just as required... where does it do the compare of "make sure all the treat codes are just as patient 9999"

Comment: There are two sets
1. The "PATIENTS" of all their "MYTREATMENT" except PATIENT with PATIENT_ID 999999999
2. The Patient treatments that you want to compare with, "COMPARETREATMENT" with COMPARETREATMENT being PATIENT_ID 999999999

Now think final result of those two sets in our query as two circles that they overlap together if they have a match

Since we GROUP BY PATIENTS.PATIENT_ID, imagine we have a set of two circles for EACH patient_id from our first set where first set is its treatment codes that gets compared against our second set containing treatment codes of patient '999999999'

Comment: If second set is subset of first set, then all elements in second set should overlap in our first set. We do a count to see how many overlap against our second set COUNT(COMPARETEMENT.TREATMENT_CODE) and check whether the number is the same as the total elements second set contains. If its a match, Patient '999999999' is a subset of said Patient_ID, which is what your illustration requirements shows from the examples you have provided. I would recommend you to read set theory as SQL programming paradigm is based around that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT P.*
  FROM Patients P JOIN
       Patients_Treatments PT
       ON (P.Patient_ID = PT.Patient_ID)
 WHERE PT.Treatment_code IN ( SELECT Treatment_code
                                FROM Patients_Treatments
                               WHERE Patient_ID = '999999999');
```